# Using $S$ and $T$ to parameterize thermodynamic state

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

During an exercise session in school we worked on Problem 1.4 in *Equilibrium Statistical Physics* by Plischke and Bergersen. This chapter is a repetition of thermodynamics, and the problem concerns a magnetic system.

At one point the teacher's assistant wrote the magnetisation $M$ as a function of $S$ and $T$ in the following way, where $H$ is the magnetic field:

$$M = M(T,H) = M(T,H(S,T)) \tag{1}$$

I questioned the validity of this parameterization, and my reasoning is as follows. Consider something more familiar; a non-magnetic one-component system with fixed $N$, having the fundamental equation (in energy form)

$$U = U(S,V) \tag{2}$$

so that

$$dU = T dS - P dV, \tag{3}$$

where

$$T = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V, \quad -P = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_S. \tag{4}$$

Now, we all know that we can write $U$ instead as a function of $T$ and $V$. This can be argued from the thermodynamic postulates via the observation that, for a given $V$, the energy $U$ is an increasing and convex function of $S$, and hence the map

$$(S,V) \mapsto (T,V) = \left( \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V, V \right) \tag{5}$$

is a bijection, making it a valid reparameterization. This is essentially the argument made in Section 3.3 of Callen's *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics*, though he simplifies further by letting $V$ be fixed just like $N$.

We can argue in a similar way to replace $V$ with $P$, but I see no way to argue for replacing $V$ with $T$ or $S$. Hence I don't see how it would be possible to parameterize the thermodynamic state by $S$ and $T$, giving $U = U(S,T)$. Indeed it seems like $S$ and $T$ contain the same information about $U$.

Now, let us return to the original question, about equation (1). Is there something special about magnetic systems that lets us parameterize it in terms of $S$ and $T$? Something particular with magnetization? Or is there something wrong with my argument, even for the simple (non-magnetic) system?

Comment: I'd agree with you. Did the teacher's assistant give reasons for inserting $H=H(T,S)$?

Comment: @kricheli He uses it to argue that $(\partial M / \partial H)_T = (\partial M / \partial H)_S +  (\partial M / \partial S)_H  (\partial S / \partial H)_T$, though I don't really follow his reasoning here either.

Comment: Maybe it's just a mistake. I'm noticing now that we should be able to write $M = M(S(T,H), H)$, and then $(\partial M / \partial H)_T = (\partial M / \partial H)_S +  (\partial M / \partial S)_H  (\partial S / \partial H)_T$ follows by the chain rule. This must have been the intended argument, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have already pointed out in Eq. (5) that $(S,V) \mapsto (T,V)$ is a bijection, now if you also assume that this bijection is a smooth one then you should be able to substitute in $dU=TdS-pdV$ without any problem and get
$$dU^*=TdS-p^*\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}dS+\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}dT\right)\\
=\left(T-p^*\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)dS+p^*\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}dT$$
where $U^*(S,T)=U(S,V(S,T))$ and $p^*(S,T)=p(S,V(S,T)).$
Defined this way you get
$$\frac{\partial U^*}{\partial S}=T-p^*\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\\
\frac{\partial U^*}{\partial T}=p^*\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}$$

In this sense I do not think that there is anything special about magnetic systems. There could be a difference as to when the bijection is smooth because in a 1st order phase transition, such as liquid $\Leftrightarrow $ gas the entropy has a jump while in a 2nd order transition such as occurring at the Curie point, ferrommagnetism $\Leftrightarrow $ paramegnetism, the entropy is constant but not its derivative.

Comment: "You have already pointed out in Eq. (5) that (S,V)↦(S,T) is a bijection". No: "hence the map

(S,V)↦(T,V)=((∂U∂S)V,V)(5)

is a bijection"

Comment: @kricheli Yes, a direct quote from the question: "This can be argued from the thermodynamic postulates via the observation that, for a given $V$, the energy $U$ is an increasing and convex function of $S$, and hence the map $(S,V) \mapsto (T,V) = \left( \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V, V \right) \tag{5}$ is a bijection, making it a valid reparameterization. "

Comment: Yeah, I'm quoting this in my comment. He is not replacing V with T as you state, but rather S with T!

Comment: @kricheli Ahh, you are right, it was a typo; I have fixed it with the rest stays, thanks.

Comment: The fact that given $V$ the mapping $(S,V) \mapsto (T,V)$ is a smooth bijection does not imply that $V$ can be expressed as a function of $T$ and $S$. Which is kind of the crucial point in the question, how this comes about. Am I missing something? What you would need, I think, is that for example $(S,V) \mapsto T$ is invertible for any given $S$, i.e. $\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}|_S \neq 0$, such that you can obtain $V=V(T,S)$, right?

Comment: @kricheli Correct, and I  think examples of singularities such as $\tfrac{\partial T}{\partial V}\vert_{S}=-\tfrac{\partial p}{\partial S}\vert_{V} = \tfrac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S\partial V}=0$ are excludable on grounds of stability.

Comment: @hyportnex This looks like a circular argument to me. Indeed you seem to assume that $(S,T)$ is a valid parameterization right at the start, when you write $V(S,T)$ and the corresponding differential $dV = (\partial V / \partial S) dS + (\partial V / \partial T) dT$.

Comment: @hyportnex A counterexample might convince you. Consider a system with fundamental equation $U(S,V) = a S^2 - b V^2$, with $a, b$ being constants. (This is a slight modification of the system in Callen's Problem 2.2-4.) It is easily verified that $T = 2 a S$ and $P = 2 b V$, and there is no way to express $U$ as just a function of $S$ and $T$.

Comment: This cannot be a *bijection* $S, V \mapsto T,V$ for stable system: $U(S,V)=aS^2-bV^2$, $dU=2aSdS-2bVdV;T=2aS;p=2bV$,$a>0;b>0$ stability demands: $\delta^2 U=\delta T \delta S-\delta p\delta V \ge 0; 2a(\delta S)^2+2b(\delta V)^2\ge 0$. So far so good. But now express it in $T,V$ which *you* assumed in your question as a *bijection*. From $dF = -SdT-pdV$ we get $\delta^2 F=\frac{c_v}{T}(\delta T)^2-\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}(\delta V)^2=\frac{c_v}{T}(\delta T)^2-2b(\delta V)^2$ is not a definite form if $c_v\ge 0$ and $b>0$ unless $c_v=0$.

Comment: This may be going over my head; I don't even know what the notation $\delta$ is supposed to mean or what stability has do with it. Perhaps I chose a bad example, but my main concerns still stand. I can only note that the map from $(S,V)$ to $(T,V)$ given by $T = 2aS$ is clearly bijective. That has nothing to do with thermodynamics; it is just a mathematical fact.

Comment: You are absolutely right $T=2aS$ and $p=2bV$ is a bijection but their derivatives are not, and I was asking for a smooth bijection in my answer above in which the derivatives are also bijection. Was I using the wrong mathematical terminology? Should I have said invertible derivative instead?  As regards those "$\delta$"-s see Kubo: Thermodynamics Section 3.7 or this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/771180/delta2-s-confusion-regarding-second-variations-in-stability-conditions/771202#771202

Comment: To see that Callen's example system, problem 2.2-4, $U=aS^2-bV^2$ is not a stable system, check up on Callen, section 8.3. Since $dU=TdS-pdV=2aSdS-2bVdV$, therefore $p=2bV$, and since both $p$ and $V$ are positive, $b>0$.  Now $-\tfrac{\partial p}{\partial V}\vert_T =\tfrac{1}{V\kappa_T}$ where $\kappa_T >0$ is the isothermal compressibility and it is positive for a stable system, otherwise it would just collapse on its own. But here $T=const \Leftrightarrow S=const$ therefore $-\tfrac{\partial (2bV)}{\partial V}\vert_T = -2b <0$ or $\kappa_T <0$, and that is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this I have come to the conclusion that the TA was probably just making a mistake. His goal was to argue that

$$\left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial H} \right)_T = \left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial S} \right)_H \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial H} \right)_T + \left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial H} \right)_S. \tag{I}$$

For the magnetic system in question $M$ and $H$ are conjugate variables; the other conjugate pair being $S$ and $T$. Hence $(S,H)$ and $(T,H)$ are both perfectly valid state space parameterizations (as are $(S,M)$ and $(T,M)$). I therefore think the TA meant to write

$$M = M(S(T,H), H). \tag{II}$$

Then (I) simply follows by the chain rule.